# React router - url changes but not the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I know this question is asked alot... I just have a specific scenario which isn't working.

I'm using Ant design AutoComplete component. For the `onSelect` I parse various values and then do a `this.props.history.push(url)` which works perfectly fine. The route is picked up and the view changes

One of the other actions I want to perform though is that when someone types into the autocomplete field and hit the **enter** key, it should go to my search page. The url does change, but the page doesnt redirect. If I hit F5 to refresh the page, it does open on the correct component.

```
<AutoComplete
  dropdownClassName="search-dropdown"
  dataSource={optionsB}
  size={this.props.size}
  onSelect={this.onSelectOption}
  onSearch={this.props.handleSearchDashboard}
  labelInValue
  optionLabelProp="option"
  className="searchArea"
  defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.searchBar = input;
    }}
    onPressEnter={e => this.goTo(e)}
  />
</AutoComplete>
```

And here is the goTo():

```
goTo = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  const url = `/search/${e.target.value}`;
  console.log("url", url);
  this.props.history.push(url);
};
```

Any suggestions as to what might be happening here?

Comment: it might help to see how your components are hooked up, also, if using redux. I've run into this issue before and the problem was with the organization of the components and their nesting, also using PureComponent vs Component

Comment: yeah there is redux in there too, its a large app so difficult to simplify but let me work on that a little and get it posted

Comment: Could you please post the configured routes